# Plugin admob-free working on android but not on ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am making an app which uses the admob-free plugin.
I am using version 0.12.1 because latest version makes the build crash.

When deploying to android, everything works fine, test ads are showing up. Unfortunately, when deploying to ios, nothing happens: at first I had admob.js.map missing (error 404) and I resolved it by generating the map file and placing it to the right folder.
Now, I have no error but nothing is showing up: interstitual nor banner. Even the little space for the banner is not shown.

How can I make this plugin work? Thanks